# É possível salvar formulários <form> no localStorage com Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, html5, firefox

Sou iniciante em Javascript e estou fazendo um protótipo de aplicação para um trabalho da faculdade, e não queria utilizar banco de dados nem nada, pois não vale a pena, preciso apenas testar o funcionamento da GUI.

Na minha aplicação, eu tenho um formulário, e gostaria de salvá-lo no localStorage.

Mas eu preciso salvar O formulário de forma que seus campos fiquem vinculados ao formulário lo local Storage. Como se fosse um objeto Json com seus atributos. (Também não sei salvar em Json).

Eu imaginei algo assim:

```
<form onsubmit="return guardaFormulario();">
        <div>
            <label for="nome"> Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="agencia"> Agência: </label>
            <input type="text" id="agencia" />
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit">Enviar sua mensagem</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

E a função acionada ao submeter o formulário:

```
function guardaFormulario(){

   /*De alguma forma que eu não sei
 Guardo o formulário com seus atributos no local Storage */

}
```

Comment: Como é um trabalho de faculdade você pode armazenar um objeto JSON no formato string na storage. Ou se você quiser algo parecido com banco de dados pesquisa sobre Web SQL que os navegadores modernos suportam.

Comment: Qual parte você já sabe e qual tem dúvida? Sua pergunta envolve várias questões, entre elas 3 fundamentais: recuperar dados do form todo, serializar os dados, persistir no local storage. Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta e resolver uma etapa por vez, abrindo novas questões para os passos seguintes à medida que for resolvendo cada um.

Comment: @Bacco dá uma olhada agora por favor?

Comment: Veja resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293265/como-salvar-objetos-javascript-no-formato-json-na-localstorage-e-depois-desseri/293275#293275

Answer (score 2):

O localStorage é bem simples de usar você usa o `setItem()` para armazenar:

```
localStorage.setItem("chave", "valor");
//Ou
localStorage.chave = "valor";
```

E o `getItem()` para recuperar esse valor:

```
localStorage.getItem("chave");
//Ou
localStorage.chave;
```

No [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) tem mais alguns exemplos

Um exemplo de uso:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' id='chave'>
  <input type='button' id='salvar' value='Salvar'>
</form>

<p id='mostrar'></p>

<script>    
    var entrada = document.getElementById('chave');

    var paragrafo = document.getElementById('mostrar');

    document.getElementById('salvar').addEventListener('click', function() {
      localStorage.chave = entrada.value;

      mostrar.innerText = localStorage.chave;
    });
</script>
```

Para salvar um objeto JSON use `stringfy()` e `parse()`:

```
localStorage.chave = JSON.stringfy({subchave1 = "valor1", subchave2: true});

var objeto = JSON.parse(localStorage.chave);
console.log(objeto.subchave1);
```

Comment: Ok, mas a questão é como salvar o formulário. Para isso, eu poderia, ao invés de indicar uma página web no "action" do formulário, utilizar uma chamada de função que salva ele no localStorage? Como ficaria o código pra isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta com um uso. Não é necessário submeter o formulário, apenas adicione um ouvinte de evento, num botão por exemplo, e salve/busque no localStorage

Comment: Mas dessa forma você está salvando cada campo do formulário sozinho, correto? Eu queria, com um formulário, salvar um "objeto" "conta de um cliente", de forma que eu pudesse recuperar os dados dessa conta pelo nome do cliente, por exemplo.

Comment: então você pode fazer como o @Thiagosilr comentou, crie um objeto e salve ele como string: `joão: "{chave1: true, chave2: 15.3, ...}"`

Comment: Isso, mas tipo, eu crio um objeto javascript, e salvo ele no localStorage daí? Como fica isso?

Comment: Adiconei a resposta como manipular objetos JSON

Comment: Posso usar um atributo como chave, e os demais como subchaves? Exemplo:         var nome = getElementById('nome');
   var agencia = getElementById('agencia');
   var conta = getElementById('conta');     localStorage.meuObjeto = JSON.stringfy(nome= "nome"{subchave1 = "agencia", subchave2: "conta"});

Comment: Vou fazer uma pergunta específica...

Comment: Você quer guardar todo html do formulário com os valores dos sues inputs?

Comment: Tipo isso. Ao preencher este formulário, eu estou criando um cliente com sua agência e conta.

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta específica a respeito de salvar este objeto originado do formulário como Json aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293265/como-salvar-objetos-javascript-no-formato-json-na-localstorage-e-depois-desseri

Comment: Algo como `localStorage.joao = {agencia: document.getElementById('agencia').value, conta: document.getElementById('conta').value}`

Comment: Exatamente! Vou tentar

Answer (score 1):

Com `localStorage` você consegue armazenar os dados de um formulário em formato de string JSON.

Usando `FormData` você armazena todos os elementos do formulário em um objeto, em seguida fazendo um `for` você adiciona as entradas em um objeto, ficará neste formato, sendo os pares *name => value*:

```
{"nome":"fulano","email":"fulano@gmail.com" ... }
```

Para recuperar os dados, você usa o `JSON.parse` para converter os dados salvos no `localStorage` em objeto JSON e usar um `for` para popular o formulário com os valores salvos.

Nesse `for` você busca os elementos do formulário pelo seu `name` e insere o respectivo valor. Mas é preciso verificar também o tipo (`type`) dos elementos, porque alguns irão receber `value` (`input`, `select`, `button`, `textarea`...) e outros `checked` (`radio` e `checkbox`).

Escrevi o código abaixo que irá fazer tudo isso.

[**Neste link**](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t4.php) você pode testar em um formulário básico.

**Código:**

```
// pega o click do botão de submit do formulário
document.body.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

   var form = document.body.querySelector("form"),
       data = new FormData(form),
       json = {}; // objeto que irá guardar os dados

   for(var dados of form){

      var typ = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").type,
          val = dados.value;

      if(typ == "radio"){
         val = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']:checked").value;
      }else if(typ == "checkbox"){
         val = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").checked;
      }else if(typ == "select-multiple"){

         var mul = [],
             els = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados.name+"']").options;
            for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
               if(els[x].selected){
               mul.push(els[x].value);
               }
            }
         val = mul;
      }

      json[dados.name] = val;
   }

   localStorage.setItem("formulario", JSON.stringify(json));

});


// recuperação dos dados guardados no localStorage
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var formulario = localStorage.getItem("formulario");

   if(formulario){ // verifico se o localStorage existe

      var form = document.body.querySelector("form");

      formulario = JSON.parse(formulario);

      for(var dados in formulario){

         var tag = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").tagName,
             typ = document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").type;

         if(tag.match(/INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/) && !typ.match(/radio|checkbox|select-multiple/)){

            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").value = formulario[dados];

         }else if(typ == "checkbox"){

            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"']").checked = formulario[dados];

         }else if(typ == "select-multiple"){
            var mul = formulario[dados];

            for(var item of mul){
               document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"'] option[value='"+item+"']").selected = true;
            }

         }else if(typ == "radio"){
            document.body.querySelector("[name='"+dados+"'][value='"+formulario[dados]+"']").checked = true;
         }

      }

   }
});
```