# Salvar div em um cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Estou começando a mexer com cookies, então não sei muito. Estava querendo que ele salvasse uma determinada `<div>` porém não sei como fazer.

Como estou fazendo:

verificar se aquele cookie existe:

```
$nomecoook = $_GET['cont'];
if(isset($_COOKIE[$nomecoook])){

}else{
    $sql="SELECT img FROM fotos WHERE tkm='$tkm'";
    $exe= mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $numrow=mysqli_num_rows($exe);
    setcookie($nomecoook,'1',(time() + (24 * 3600)));
}
```

a div que quero salvar:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
     <?php
        $i=0;
        while($row=MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY($exe)){
           $i++;
           $img=$row['img'];
           if($i==1){
      ?>
           <div class="item active">
               <img src="../_img/<?php echo e($img) ?>" alt="First Slide">
           </div>
      <?php
           }else{
      ?>
           <div class="item">
               <img src="../_img/<?php echo e($img) ?>" alt="Second Slide">
           </div>
      <?php
           }
      }
      ?>
</div>
```

Quero salvar o resultado dessa div para não ter que fazer outra consulta no banco de dados. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Ou se tiver uma maneira de salvar a página toda naquele cookie.

Comment: Geralmente o próprio navegador cuida disso, mantendo alguns dados salvos em cache e atualizando as vezes, mas se quer salvar o conteúdo em um cookie mesmo, sugiro guardar só o essencial no formato json (com `json_encode`) e, quando for usar, transforma esse json em um array ou objeto (`json_decode`) pra usar. Se quer salvar todo o html (não recomendo), crie uma string e vai adicionando os elementos nessa string em vez de fazer `echo`

Comment: Caramba, que susto! Pelo título parece que quer salvar o elemento `div` dentro do Cookie!

Comment: Opa, mas pera aí. Tá falando de salvar a página toda . Poderia explicar o que você pretende fazer com isso?  Não estou falando do que quer fazer com o código, mas o objetivo disso para o usuário final. Não faz nenhum sentido querer colocar uma página interna numa div.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam como faço para usar o cache?,
WallaceMaxters n quero salvar a pagina todo em uma div quero que ao usuario entrar uma vez aquele conteudo fique salvo e na proxima vez carregue mais rapido n sabia q tinha o cache para isso

Comment: O navegador cuida do cache, não precisa ativar (mas pode ser desativado no dev tools). Se você quer salvar determinados conteúdos então sugiro usar localStorage para isso

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam sou novo nessa area então poderia me explicar copmo se usa isso

Comment: [Como usar localStorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293235/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-salvar-formul%C3%A1rios-form-no-localstorage-com-javascript-puro/293238#293238)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua intenção me parece ser utilizar um cache, para evitar consultas ao banco de dados.

Você precisa pensar bem se isso é viável, primeiramente. Os dados que estão consultando são alterados constantemente? Ou nunca?

Se a resposta for "nunca", aí podemos passar para o próximo parágrafo.

Você sabia que [o Cookie tem um limite de tamanho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2476/n%C3%BAmero-e-tamanho-m%C3%A1ximo-de-cookies)? já pensou que "salvar a página inteira" ou uma "div" pode ser impossível ou inviável?

Outra coisa: Sabe que o cookie, diferente da sessão, poderia ter os valores modificados diretamente no navegador.

Se você salvar a DIV no Cookie e usá-lo para escrever o conteúdo salvo nele pelo PHP, por exemplo, sabia que isso pode deixar seu site [vulnerável ao XSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10921/ataques-xss-como-ocorre)?

No seu caso, me parece um caso para o uso de Sessão ou mesmo de usar um `Header` para determinar uma resposta baseada em um cache ou não.

Um pequeno exemplo abaixo para ver como poderia ficar a utilização do header `Last-Modified` (já usei em alguns casos e funciona muito bem):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) {

    if (strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) < time()) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
        // não executará a consulta, mas dará a última resposta, que foi salva no cache do navegador
        exit;
    }
}



header(sprintf("Last-Modified: %s", (new DateTime())->format(DateTime::COOKIE)));

// faça a sua consulta aqui
```

O código acima é bem simples e você pode adaptá-lo muito bem à sua necessidade. Não pretendo dar uma resposta no sentido de fazer pra você, mas quero que entenda o que, para o seu caso, cookie não resolve.

**Informação importante**: Alguns navegadores ignoram o `Last-Modified` quando usado em `localhost`. Então, para testes, talvez você poderia ter dificuldades, caso use ele. Creio que eu resolvi isso criando um domínio fictício no arquivo `hosts`.

Veja algumas respostas sobre cache, sessão e afins:

- [Guardar ou não cache do navegador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94372/guardar-ou-n%C3%A3o-cache-do-navegador)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers?rq=1

Comment: O que acha de localStorage? Dentre as três (cookie, http e storage) qual considera melhor?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam cookie e storage, como eu disse na resposta, é no navegador. qualquer pessoa pode abrir o console e alterar o conteúdo. isso deixaria o site vulnerável ao XSS (o cara pode escrever um javascript malicioso e colocar no lugar do conteúdo da "div"). Eu sugiro fazer essas coisas pelo servidor... ou seja: Sessão ou Header

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam como o wallace disse, isso abre possibilidade de ataques, não que alguém não possa fazer manualmente no localStorage pelo F12, e claro que dá para tratar o conteudo, mas é complicado, fora que se a intenção é cache é melhor usar a interface que já tem, tentar resolver na base de tecnologias do "front-end" algo assim é ter que escrever muita coisa, pode dar certo para um app hibrido, e poderá até ser uma boa ideia nesse caso, mas se tratando de páginas web é complicar demais

Comment: Quando digo storage, imagino algo salvo no lado cliente e que não volta pro servidor, por exemplo é salvo os dados necessários (urls, textos, a data em que foi salvo o conteúdo), quando passar determinado tempo (sla 1 dia), então o cliente pede o conteúdo novamente, sem mandar nada do que foi salvo em storage, apenas uma requisição comum, que seria igual ao usar o http

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam então, jovenzinho... quando você usa o `header` (que foi o que respondi "http") você está fazendo o navegador pegar a informação que ele salvou antes no disco, mediante a informação passada pelo Last-Modified.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters muito muito obrigado não sabia dessa limitação e nem dessa vulnerabilidade existente, irei lhe explicar meu caso e se possivel gostaria que me falesse se e viavel usar cache pois sou novo no assunto.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o casso e: tenho uma pagina chamada `conteudo.php` e nela eu uso ` $_GET` que pega o ID da url ` conteudo.php?id=1` eu estou querendo que se a pessoa ja acessou aquela pagina daquele id ele salve e da proxima vez que ele for abrir a pagina ela carregue mais rapido usando as informações ja salva. para isso e recomendado usar cache?

Comment: @CyberHacker depende. O que vem do "id" pode ser alterado? Ou é algo que você registra apenas uma vez? De qualquer forma, mesmo que a resposta seja "não", você salva a data de modificação no banco? Se sim, é a sua salvação.

Comment: @CyberHacker resumindo: Se você tem uma data de modificação salva no banco, basta trocar o trecho do meu código onde tem `DateTime` e colocar a data que vem do banco.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o conteudo dessa ID e salvo apenas 1 vez e n e alterado mais

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81235/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-cyber-hacker).